# how can I download apache jena and add libaries?

Tags: netbeans, jena

I have a question about install jena.

I do not know how install it. but i was working with Netbeans and Jena. i download apach Jena binaries. but give me a error that "could not be saved , because the source file could not be read."
How can I download apach jena and use libraries in netbeans ?(step download and add library in netbeans)

Comment: I'm not a NetBeans user, but I do use Jena, and “installing” Jena should be a matter of making the appropriate JAR files available to your development environment.  As such, the answer to a [question like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4393127/1281433) about installing JARs so that NetBeans can find them will probably work for you.

Comment: thank you. but how can i use apach jena? where is jar file in jena?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Jena distributions page](http://jena.apache.org/download/index.html) lists some download links;  If you get, e.g., `apache-jena-2.10.1.tar.gz` from the [binaries page](http://www.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/), then when you unpack that tarball, you'll get an `apache-2.10.1` directory, with a `lib` directory within, and the JARs in that directory are what you need:

```
+- apache-jena-2.10.1
 +- lib
  +- ...
  +- jena-arq-2.10.1.jar
  +- jena-core-2.10.1.jar
  +- jena-iri-0.9.6.jar
  +- jena-tdb-0.10.1.jar
  +- ...
```

You'll actually need *all* the JARs in that directory on your classpath, not just the ones starting with `jena-`.

Comment: thank u.  but when I download apach-2.10.1 then What to do? i download this files but I got an error. and i can not open this.like this: could not be saved , because the source file could not be read.

Comment: @sima412 You can download [apache-jena-2.10.1.tar.gz](http://www.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/apache-jena-2.10.1.tar.gz) or [apache-jena-2.10.1.zip](http://www.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/apache-jena-2.10.1.zip). These are compressed archive that needs to be extracted with `tar -xzf` or `unzip`.  After extraction, you should end up with the directory structure that I described.  If you're having a problem extracting the archive, you'll need to add more detail to your question (e.g., the actual error message).  Also, it's probably not a Jena specific issue. Can you open other archives files?

Comment: thank you joshaua taylor. yes i can open other archives. i do not konw where is the problem. the acyual error is "could not be saved , because the source file could not be read". so i try again and donload apache jena. i hope that This time it is run.

Comment: Yes, but is that happening when you're trying to download the file (which "could not be saved" suggests), when you're trying to extract it, or …?

Comment: when I Download the zip file not happening but I want to open the download file this  is happening.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem;  I'm able to download the [apache-jena-2.10.1.zip](http://www.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/apache-jena-2.10.1.zip) and unzip it.  I'd suggest that you find another user, see whether they can download and unzip the file, and if they can, try to determine the difference in your setups.  If they cannot, you might want to post a question about it, perhaps on http://superuser.com (another StackExchange site).